# Select part of Button's text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using this code to create buttons with two lines text

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int top = 50;
    int left = 100;
    int n = 0;
    int s = 99;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Left = left;
        button.Top = top;
        panel1.Controls.Add(button); // here
        button.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        if (i == 4 || i == 9||i==14||i==19)
        {
            top = 30;
            left = 23;
            top +=button.Top+2;
            left += button.Width+2;
        }
        else
            left += button.Width + 2;

        n = n + 1;
        s = s + 1;

        button.Text = Convert.ToString(n) + Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToString(s);
        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }       
}
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string s;
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    s = button.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

So I need to select only second line brom my button text when I click dynamic button. How will I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store some data in `Tag` property:

```
button.Text = Convert.ToString(n) + Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToString(s);
button.Tag = new int[] { n, s };
```

and later retrive it and use:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    var data = button.Tag as int[];
    string s = data[1].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string s;
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    s = button.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    MessageBox.Show(button.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
}
```